# Arm Cortex-M4 Sub Routines Unexpected Behavior

Tags: assembly, arm, subroutine

```
        .include "Equates.s"

        .syntax unified
        .text
        .global main
        .global Delay
        .global Top

Delay:    mov     r1,r3
          ldr    r2,=#0x000AAE60
          mul    r1,r2
Dloop:    subs    r1, #1
          bne     Dloop
          bx      lr

BlinkLed:   push    {lr}

Blink:
            mov             r3,#2
            bl      LEDGreenOn
            bl      Delay
            bl      LEDGreenOff
            bl      Delay
            bl      CheckButton
            cmp     r0,#1
            bne             ButtonNotPressed

            bl      LEDOrangeOn
            bl      Delay
            bl      LEDOrangeOff
            bl      Delay
            bl      CheckButton
            cmp     r0,#1
            bne     ButtonNotPressed

            bl      LEDBlueOn
            bl      Delay
            bl      LEDBlueOff
            bl      Delay
            bl      CheckButton
            cmp     r0,#1
            bne     ButtonNotPressed

            bl      LEDRedOn
            bl      Delay
            bl      LEDRedOff
            bl      Delay
            bl      CheckButton
            cmp     r0,#1
            beq     Blink
                bne             ButtonNotPressed


ButtonNotPressed:
            bl      CheckButton
            cmp     r0,#1
            bne     ButtonNotPressed
                bl              BinaryCount
            pop     {lr}
            b       Top

main:
            bl      InitButton
            bl      InitLEDs

Top:                bl      CheckButton
            cmp     r0,#1
            bne     Top
            bl      BlinkLed

            .end
```

I am trying to blink one light for one second while the button is held down, if I stop pressing the button on my board, then I want the lights to be off and the code to start waiting on me to start pressing again. If I do, then I want it to go to BinaryCount to do its thing. However, I am getting unexpected results, sometimes it works but sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it works just the way I want, but sometimes it never reaches BinaryCount. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can somebody point me in the right direction, please?

Here's the rest of my code:

```
        .include "Equates.s"

        .syntax unified
        .text
        .global InitButton
        .global CheckButton


InitButton:

            ldr     r0,=RCC
            ldr     r1,[r0,AHBENR]
            orr     r1,#GPIOAEN
            str     r1,[r0,AHBENR]
            ldr     r0,=GPIOA
            ldr     r1,[r0,#MODER]
            bic     r1,#0x03
            str     r1,[r0,#MODER]
            bx      lr


CheckButton:

            ldr     r0,=GPIOA
            ldrh    r0,[r0,#IDR]
            and     r0,#0x01
            bx      lr

            .end
```

```
        .include "Equates.s"

        .syntax unified
        .text
        .global BinaryCount

BinaryCount:
            mov     r5,#-1

CountLoop:
            add     r5,#1
            cmp     r5,#15
            bgt     ResetCount
            ldr     r0,=GPIOB
            mov     r1,r5
            lsl     r1,r1,#6
            ldrh    r2,[r0,#ODR]
            bic     r2,#0x0FC0
            orr     r2,r1
            strh    r2,[r0,#ODR]
            mov     r3,#1
            bl      Delay
            bl      CheckButton
            cmp     r0,#1
            beq     CountLoop
            bl      AllLEDsOff
            b       Top

ResetCount:

            mov     r5,#0
            b       CountLoop

            .end
```

```
        .include "Equates.s"

        .syntax unified
        .text
        .global InitLEDs
        .global LEDGreenOff
        .global LEDOrangeOff
        .global LEDBlueOff
        .global LEDRedOff
        .global LEDGreenOn
        .global LEDOrangeOn
        .global LEDBlueOn
        .global LEDRedOn
        .global AllLEDsOff

InitLEDs:

            ldr     r0,=RCC
            ldr     r1,[r0,AHBENR]
            orr     r1,#GPIOBEN
            str     r1,[r0,AHBENR]
            ldr     r0,=GPIOB
            ldr     r1,[r0,#MODER]
            bic     r1,#0x000FF000
            orr     r1,#0x00055000
            str     r1,[r0,#MODER]

            ldrh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bic     r1,#0x03C0
            strh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bx      lr

LEDGreenOn:
            ldr     r0,=GPIOB
            ldrh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            orr     r1,#0x0200
            strh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bx      lr

LEDGreenOff:
            ldr     r0,=GPIOB
            ldrh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bic     r1,#0x0200
            strh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bx      lr

LEDOrangeOn:
            ldr     r0,=GPIOB
            ldrh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            orr     r1,#0x0100
            strh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bx      lr

LEDOrangeOff:
            ldr     r0,=GPIOB
            ldrh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bic     r1,#0x0100
            strh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bx      lr

LEDBlueOn:
            ldr     r0,=GPIOB
            ldrh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            orr     r1,#0x0080
            strh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bx      lr

LEDBlueOff:
            ldr     r0,=GPIOB
            ldrh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bic     r1,#0x0080
            strh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bx      lr

LEDRedOn:
            ldr     r0,=GPIOB
            ldrh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            orr     r1,#0x0040
            strh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bx      lr

LEDRedOff:
            ldr     r0,=GPIOB
            ldrh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bic     r1,#0x0040
            strh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bx      lr

AllLEDsOff:
            ldr     r0,=GPIOB
            ldrh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bic     r1,#0x0FC0
            strh    r1,[r0,#ODR]
            bx      lr

            .end
```

The lights to work green, orange, blue, red and then jump to binary count.

Comment: *but sometimes it never reaches BinaryCount.* - I assume you are using a debugger to be able to see that.  So what *does* happen instead?  "It doesn't work" isn't a useful problem description, and that bit I quoted seems like the only specific detail to go with your not-very-minimal [mcve].

Comment: When using the debugger it works if button is pressed it goes to binary count. If it doesn’t it goes to button not pressed and it keeps looping there until somebody presses the button.

Comment: If I just run it then it works, blinks green orange blue red and it keeps going if button pressed. If not pressed SOMETIMES it jumps to binary count and it counts up to 15 and it keeps looping it until I release the button.

Comment: But it’s buggy because sometimes if I release the button during the first blink led instead of going to binary count when I press the button again it starts blinking from where it left off.

Comment: I dont see your debugging work shown in the question...

Comment: It seem correct.  Do you need 'de-bounce'?  It is a topic that is for buttons.  This can cause strange behaviour.  https://www.google.com/search?q=button+debounce